# Adding new text field using if/then python statement?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, python-parser

I was hoping someone could help me with an issue I've been having while trying to aggregate data into a new column in an attribute table in arcgis. This is part of a model built using model builder. I added a new column, but the model always fails when it reaches the part where it has to populate the new column.

I'm trying to group specific land uses into a new land type (for example: field, pasture, and crop should all be coded as 'Agriculture' in the new column). I have been using the field calculator tool to populate the new column, but it's not working. I think either field calculator is the wrong tool to use in this scenario, or my python is wrong. Any advice? My python is below.

```
def landuse_groupFromName(LUDCODE):    
if LUDCODE in ['23', '1', '36', '35', '2']: 
return 'Agriculture'   
elif LUDCODE in ['15', '16', '5']:
return 'Commercial/Industry'    
elif LUDCODE in ['11', '10']:       
return 'High_Density_Res'    
elif LUDCODE in ['13', '38']:
return 'Low_Density_Res'   
elif LUDCODE in ['12']:  
return 'Med_Density_Res'    
elif LUDCODE in ['34', '26', '29', '7', '8', '17', '9']:        
return 'Recreation'    
elif LUDCODE in ['18']:       
return 'Transportation'    
elif LUDCODE in ['31']:        
return 'Urban'    
elif LUDCODE in ['39', '19']:       
return 'Waste'    
elif LUDCODE in ['20']:       
return 'Water'    
elif LUDCODE in ['37', '14']:        
return 'Wetlands'    
elif LUDCODE in ['40', '3', '4', '6', '24', '25']:        
return 'Wild'    
else:        
return 'undefined'
```

Comment: Fix your indention

Comment: Is that indentation indicative or is it caused by formatting into GIS.SE? I have noticed multiple return statements aren't liked by the field calculator, try replacing return with Rval = then on the last line return Rval.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson I think indentation is formatted in GIS SE.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.

Comment: Are you looking up integers/numbers?  Or are you looking up values stored as text?  should `elif LUDCODE in ['15', '16', '5']:` rather be `elif LUDCODE in [15, 16, 5]:`?

Comment: Do you have an expression in the expression box that is calling this code?

Comment: Definitely calculator looking like a wrong tool this time. Fill table in Excel, join, calculate.

Answer (score 2):

Indentation need to be fixed. Be careful for indentation when working with Python. Try below:

```
def landuse_groupFromName(LUDCODE):    
    if LUDCODE in ['23', '1', '36', '35', '2']: 
        return 'Agriculture'   
    elif LUDCODE in ['15', '16', '5']:
        return 'Commercial/Industry'    
    elif LUDCODE in ['11', '10']:       
        return 'High_Density_Res'    
    elif LUDCODE in ['13', '38']:
        return 'Low_Density_Res'   
    elif LUDCODE in ['12']:  
        return 'Med_Density_Res'    
    elif LUDCODE in ['34', '26', '29', '7', '8', '17', '9']:        
        return 'Recreation'    
    elif LUDCODE in ['18']:       
        return 'Transportation'    
    elif LUDCODE in ['31']:        
        return 'Urban'    
    elif LUDCODE in ['39', '19']:       
        return 'Waste'    
    elif LUDCODE in ['20']:       
        return 'Water'    
    elif LUDCODE in ['37', '14']:        
        return 'Wetlands'    
    elif LUDCODE in ['40', '3', '4', '6', '24', '25']:        
        return 'Wild'    
    else:        
        return 'undefined'
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the reason your code is failing is because you are looking for text values - `elif LUDCODE in ['15', '16', '5']:` - rather than numeric values - `elif LUDCODE in [15, 16, 5]:`.  Python won't find text in a numeric field.

You can put everything into a python dictionary and have a single lookup/return for your values rather than multiple if/elif/else.

```
def landuse_groupFromName(LUDCODE):    
    lookupDict = {
                   1: 'Agriculture',
                   2: 'Agriculture',
                  23: 'Agriculture',
                  35: 'Agriculture',
                  36: 'Agriculture',
                   5: 'Commercial/Industry',
                  15: 'Commercial/Industry',
                  16: 'Commercial/Industry',
                  10: 'High_Density_Res',
                  11: 'High_Density_Res',
                  13: 'Low_Density_Res',
                  38: 'Low_Density_Res',
                  12: 'Med_Density_Res',
                   7: 'Recreation',
                   8: 'Recreation',
                   9: 'Recreation',
                  17: 'Recreation',
                  26: 'Recreation',
                  29: 'Recreation',
                  34: 'Recreation',
                  18: 'Transportation', 
                  31: 'Urban',
                  19: 'Waste',
                  39: 'Waste',
                  20: 'Water', 
                  14: 'Wetlands',
                  37: 'Wetlands',
                   3: 'Wild',
                   4: 'Wild',
                   6: 'Wild',
                  24: 'Wild', 
                  25: 'Wild',
                  40: 'Wild'
                 }
    if LUDCODE in lookupDict:
        return lookupDict[LUDCODE]
    else:
        return 'undefined'
```

As I mentioned at the start, if your values in the `LUDCODE` field are actually stored as text rather than as numeric you will need to surround every value with quote marks e.g. `'1': 'Agriculture',`